# HTML wont link to CSS file in Visual Studio Code

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

I am trying to link my css formatting to an HTML document.

[image]

As you can see, my CSS is link is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
```

And my CSS file is titled style.css in a folder called css.
Why is it not linking?

Comment: Where is the CSS in relation to the HTML?  Is it off the root and you need a / on the front?

Comment: We can't definitively answer without knowing the file structure of your site. Do a little research on path types (absolute, relative, root-relative and protocol-agnostic) then choose the one that best suits your needs and format your path appropriatly.

Answer (score 3):

I would add the attribute type and value "text/css"
Your link tag would end up like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"
```

Comment: Yes, thanks! This is the answer

Answer (score 2):

The question is: Where is your html file? Obviously not in the root folder, but probably in another sub folder. Try this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" />
```

This navigates one level up and then into the `css` folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you have any project structure with seperate subfolders for ".html" file, ".css" file, ".js" file  etc and you are trying to link your ".html" file to ".css" file then:

- In html file, give the path of your ".css" file in 
  **href = "../folderName/filename.css"**

  such as: "`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css"/>` "

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading static file into html then you should mention in html code that you are loading static files explicitly.
See the below code:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>

<head lang="en">

    <title>SuperStore DashBoard</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/superstore.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}" />
    <script src="{% static 'js/bundle.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/superstore.js' %}"></script>

</head>
<body>
</body>

</html>
```

These two are css static files

```
href="{% static 'css/superstore.css' %}"
href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}"
```

These are static javascript files

```
src="{% static 'js/bundle.js' %}"
src="{% static 'js/superstore.js' %}"
```

css and js are folder name in visual studio code.

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

You have to mention static files before the start of your html code.