# html not linking to css file in Visual Studio Code

Tags: html, css, windows, visual-studio-code

## Environment

- Windows 8.1 64bit
- Visual Studio Code 1.15.1

## Related question

- [HTML wont link to CSS file in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863458/html-wont-link-to-css-file-in-visual-studio-code)

## Issue

### html doesn't link to css

1. Classes and ids in css don't show up on Intellisense in html.
2. When I put the cursor on a class or id in html and press F12 to jump to css, a window pops up and says "the definition wasn't found."

However, when I open the html in a browser, the webpage is shown perfectly fine. So it seems like there is something wrong with my Visual Studio Code.

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="abc"></div>
  <div id="xyz"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

**css**

```
.abc{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}

#xyz{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
}
```

**files**

index.html
css
|
+---style.css

**webpage**

[image]

I'd like to know how to get rid of this issue.

## Edit 17/9/3 19:03

Thanks for the answers, guys.
The following didn't work.

- `href="../css/style.css"`
- `href="~/css/style.css"`
- `href="css/style.css"`
- Embedding stylesheet in  tag (And I want to keep css in a separate file)

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe jumping to css classes and ids is supported natively by Vscode.  Try the [CSS Peek](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pranaygp.vscode-css-peek) extension, it does what you want nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the path you provided to access style.css file is correct.
If that doesn't work, try adding inline css in index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
.abc{
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     background: red;
    }

#xyz{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="abc"></div>
<div id="xyz"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

This is an alternative Solution.

According to me your browser is not refreshing the file so you can refresh/reload the entire page by pressing     CTRL + F5    in windows for mac 
    CMD + R

Try it if still getting problem then you can test it by using firebug tool for firefox.

For IE8 and Google Chrome you can check it by pressing F12 your developer tool will pop-up and you can see the Html and css.

You can also try this syntax:

```
<link href="./css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"/>
```

Make sure that the browser actually makes the request and doesn't return a 404.

Hope It Helps!!

Comment: Maybe ./css should be ../css too ?

Comment: Depends in which directory you are. Depending on that you should be able to generate a relative path.

Answer (score -1):

If html and css are in the same directory, it should work.
How could it be it doesn't?
Well, if the preview copys the html to a temporary directory before showing it, the css will not be there. That's the only way I can imagine this problem exists.