# Issue in applying external CSS file

Tags: html, css, jsp

This is the [structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFlAA.png) of my project. I am not able to apply the css file called cover.css in the jsp file called indexprova.jsp file. Can anyone help me? I'm losing a lot of time. Thanks in advance . I attached the css code, the jsp file and an image so that the situation is more comprehensible .

```css
/*
 * Globals
 */

/* Links */
a,
a:focus,
a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

/* Custom default button */
.btn-secondary,
.btn-secondary:hover,
.btn-secondary:focus {
  color: #333;
  text-shadow: none; /* Prevent inheritance from `body` */
  background-color: #fff;
  border: .05rem solid #fff;
}


/*
 * Base structure
 */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
}
body {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 .05rem .1rem rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

/* Extra markup and styles for table-esque vertical and horizontal centering */
.site-wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; /* For at least Firefox */
  min-height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5rem rgba(0,0,0,.5);
          box-shadow: inset 0 0 5rem rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
.site-wrapper-inner {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.cover-container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

/* Padding for spacing */
.inner {
  padding: 2rem;
}


/*
 * Header
 */

.masthead {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.masthead-brand {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link {
  padding: .25rem 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: .25rem solid transparent;
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link:hover,
.nav-masthead .nav-link:focus {
  border-bottom-color: rgba(255,255,255,.25);
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link + .nav-link {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.nav-masthead .active {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}

@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .masthead-brand {
    float: left;
  }
  .nav-masthead {
    float: right;
  }
}


/*
 * Cover
 */

.cover {
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
}
.cover .btn-lg {
  padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/*
 * Footer
 */

.mastfoot {
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}


/*
 * Affix and center
 */

@media (min-width: 40em) {
  /* Pull out the header and footer */
  .masthead {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
  }
  .mastfoot {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  /* Start the vertical centering */
  .site-wrapper-inner {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  /* Handle the widths */
  .masthead,
  .mastfoot,
  .cover-container {
    width: 100%; /* Must be percentage or pixels for horizontal alignment */
  }
}

@media (min-width: 62em) {
  .masthead,
  .mastfoot,
  .cover-container {
    width: 42rem;
  }
}
```

```html
[![<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="/src/main/webapp/resources/css/cover.css" rel="stylesheet" >
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="site-wrapper">

      <div class="site-wrapper-inner">

        <div class="cover-container">

          <div class="masthead clearfix">
            <div class="inner">
              <h3 class="masthead-brand">Cover</h3>
              <nav class="nav nav-masthead">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
              </nav>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="inner cover">
            <h1 class="cover-heading">Cover your page.</h1>
            <p class="lead">Cover is a one-page template for building simple and beautiful home pages. Download, edit the text, and add your own fullscreen background photo to make it your own.</p>
            <p class="lead">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary">Learn more</a>
            </p>
          </div>

          <div class="mastfoot">
            <div class="inner">
              <p>Cover template for <a href="https://getbootstrap.com">Bootstrap</a>, by <a href="https://twitter.com/mdo">@mdo</a>.</p>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>]
```

Comment: Try using this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46020589/html-not-linking-to-css-file-in-visual-studio-code/46020700#46020700

Comment: Did you check the error in Chrome F12 developer network tab

Comment: Try ref="/css/cover.css"

Comment: @user7294900 doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think that your path is simply wrong. This should work `../../resources/css/cover.css`

Generally in this situation my debugging process is like this:

1. Find out what directory are you in:
   move your cover.css file around and check when `<link href="cover.css">` will work.
   Start with moving css file to the same directory your jsp file is.
2. Move your css file one directory up and check `<link href="../cover.css">`
3. Move css file to your destination directory and figure out path.

I made test project with your files and it's working fine. Check if you have anything in console.
[image]

Comment: Do you have your page online that I can access it and check the console?

Comment: I have upload the project www.albomanutentori.it you can test the css pressing on the home "Accedi2" it's work but when im programming no ;(

Comment: How do you test in your environment? Try to simply open indexprova.jsp in Chrome. I made test page and is working fine form me .../../resources/css/cover.css is ok

Comment: i test with chrome